# PSQL command-line option to require transactions

Tags: psql

I'd like to stop myself from doing something stupid.  I'd like to tell `psql` to reject any DML (updates, inserts) that isn't explicitly enclosed in a transaction.

```
postgres=# update  "employees" set salary = salary * 1.5;
ERROR:  cannot update outside of a transaction 
postgres=# start transaction;
START TRANSACTION
postgres=# update  "employees" set salary = salary * 1.5;
UPDATE 331805
postgres=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
postgres=#
```

Actually, what would be almost as good (and better in some situations) for me would be an option that forbid psql from executing any DML at all.

(Yes, in a formal sense, I could just "stop doing stupid things", but you know, baby steps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`\set autocommit off`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) to automatically open a new transaction and not commit it immediately if you run standalone statements. This applies to all statement types.

There's no facility to prohibit or control DML separately to DDL though. To `psql` they're just statements.

For scripts you should also use `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`.

If you're keen you could write an `ExecutorStart_hook` as a C extension  loaded via `session_preload_libraries` that checks a configuration variable (GUC) set by the `psql` session and uses that to `ERROR` if DML is attempted while still permitting DDL (which runs through `ProcessUtility_hook` instead). You will need basic C programming knowledge and to read the PostgreSQL manual on extensions plus some of the example extensions.

Comment: Well, select is not much different with or without commit.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to do this manually in psql is:

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

(Capitals, not lowercase like in the other answer)

Note: The autocommit-on mode is PostgreSQL's traditional behavior, but autocommit-off is closer to the SQL spec. If you prefer autocommit-off, you might wish to set it in the system-wide psqlrc file or your ~/.psqlrc file.